# Postgis Geo Elevation Raster: Get average Elevation

Tags: postgis, raster, elevation

I am running Postgresql 9.5.5 with Postgis 2.2.1 on Ubuntu. I have imported [ASTER GDEM](https://asterweb.jpl.nasa.gov/gdem.asp) elevation information as a raster and query it for elevation using geo coordinates.
Currently I use

```
ST_NearestValue(elevation.rast, ST_SetSRID($POINT,4326), false)
```

With (e.g.)

```
$POINT = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(8.4255, 49.0113), 4326)
```

but as ASTER GDEM is "only" sampled at 30m x 30m I need to get a (weighted) average of the nearest 4 or 16 available samples. Which is the most elegant (and performant) way to do this?

I tried

```
SELECT (ST_Intersection(elevation.rast, ST_Expand($POINT),0.0001))).val
FROM elevation
WHERE ST_Intersects(elevation.rast, ST_Expand($POINT),0.0001));
```

but this only returns the height without the exact position, so the samples can not be weighted by distance. It also seems rather ugly and the expansion factor needs to be calculated depending on the latitude.

I am rather new to postgis and may have missed even a simple solution.

Comment: Have you read this? https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/WKTRasterTutorial01

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Meanwhile I have moved on and have a follow up [question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223554/postgis-self-intersection-on-geometry-raster-comparison)